# Gesture recognizer with Voice Over active

Tags: ios

I developed an application which allows to the user to draw his finger signature in a canvas.
This feature is implemented using UIPanGestureRecognizer with a specific target action to draw a line in a UIView, but when the “Voice Over” is active the gesture recognizer action is not triggered anymore.

Gesture initialize code

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Gesture action code

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    CGPoint currentPoint = [pan locationInView:self];
    CGPoint midPoint = midpoint(previousPoint, currentPoint);

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [path moveToPoint:currentPoint];
    }
    else if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:midPoint controlPoint:previousPoint];
    }

    previousPoint = currentPoint;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Is there any way to draw a line in a view using gesture with “Voice Over” active?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709260/swipe-gesture-recogniser-using-voiceover

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my problem setting both isAccessibilityElement and accessibilityTraits properties for UIView canvas:

```
canvasView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
canvasView.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction;
```